# how to merge multiple subtitle files in python?

Tags: python, merge

I have a batch of files "srt" I want to merge

sub1.srt

```
1
00:00:21,601 --> 00:00:24,130
- What happened? - It's a mess, I heard.

2
00:00:24,131 --> 00:00:25,900
- What's that? - Dead bodies?

3
00:00:25,901 --> 00:00:28,839
- What's going on? - I wish I knew.
```

sub2.srt

```
1
00:00:28,840 --> 00:00:31,310
No one knows. They won't say.

2
00:00:31,311 --> 00:00:35,276
- My gosh. - How can so many die?

3
00:00:45,191 --> 00:00:46,556
When you starve,
```

after merge

```
1
00:00:21,601 --> 00:00:24,130
- What happened? - It's a mess, I heard.

2
00:00:24,131 --> 00:00:25,900
- What's that? - Dead bodies?

3
00:00:25,901 --> 00:00:28,839
- What's going on? - I wish I knew.

4
00:00:28,840 --> 00:00:31,310
No one knows. They won't say.

5
00:00:31,311 --> 00:00:35,276
- My gosh. - How can so many die?

6
00:00:45,191 --> 00:00:46,556
When you starve,
```

I found this script that it works The problem is in the numbers The subtitle are not in order

```
filenames = ['sub1.srt', 'sub2.srt']
with open('output_file.srt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

appear unordered

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
import re

re_sub_no = re.compile(r"^\s*\d+\s*$", re.MULTILINE)

def repl(match):
    global sub_no
    sub_no += 1
    return str(sub_no)

sub_no = 0
filenames = ["sub1.srt", "sub2.srt"]
with open("sub_merged.srt", "w") as fout:
    for name in filenames:
        with open(name, "r") as fin:
            fout.write(re_sub_no.sub(repl, fin.read()) + "\n\n")
```

The regex-pattern `re_sub_no` is searching for the sub-numbers, and via the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.sub) the `repl`-function makes sure the numbering is consistent. The `sub_no` variable is made `global` because the function itself can't store the current state of the numbering otherwise. The `\s*`-parts of the pattern are only a precaution in case of whitespace before/after the number, maybe you don't need them (try it without).

---

The code above doesn't address the encoding of the files. When you run the following for the files that you've linked to

```
import chardet

for name in ["sub1.srt", "sub2.srt"]:
    with open(name, "br") as file:
        print(chardet.detect(file.read()))
```

the result will, most likely, be

```
{'encoding': 'UTF-8-SIG', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
{'encoding': 'UTF-8-SIG', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
```

So, the following modification should hopefully work:

```
...
with open("sub_merged.srt", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as fout:
    for name in filenames:
        with open(name, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as fin:
            fout.write(re_sub_no.sub(repl, fin.read()) + "\n\n")
```

For future use, you could combine that into:

```
import chardet, re

filenames = ["sub1.srt", "sub2.srt"]
encodings = []
for name in filenames:
    with open(name, "br") as file:
        encodings.append(chardet.detect(file.read())["encoding"])

re_sub_no = re.compile(r"^\d+\s*$", re.MULTILINE)

def repl(match):
    global sub_no
    sub_no += 1
    return str(sub_no)

sub_no = 0
with open("sub_merged.srt", "w", encoding=encodings[0]) as fout:
    for name, encoding in zip(filenames, encodings):
        with open(name, "r", encoding=encoding) as fin:
            fout.write(re_sub_no.sub(repl, fin.read()) + "\n\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, a script that works, but the problem of empty space between subtitles does not exist. Is there a solution for it? When I test subtitles with a movie it doesn't work

Comment: @japey49036m I don't quite understand the problem, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: I mean an empty space between each translation that doesn't exist  https://i.imgur.com/KQy41lE.jpg

Comment: @japey49036m If you're referring to the `\s*`: That's for potential whitespace _within_ a line. But the file in the screenshot looks odd: There's a 1 between 29 and 30 - how did that happen?

Comment: The problem occurred some merge sub1+sub2

Comment: @japey49036m Hm, I don't see how this could happen with the code above - provided the input files are in order? Can you share the files somewhere s.t. I can try it?

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/q55p0hqkh5lz2kzbn7emtuawe2yvb95t

Comment: @japey49036m Thanks. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This script will append subs from the second SRT file to the closest *existing* timings in the first SRT file.

Requires the [`srt`](https://github.com/cdown/srt) module that needs to be installed with `pip3 install srt`.

##### Usage

```sh
# by default output to subs1_MERGED.srt
python3 srt_merge.py subs1.srt subs2.srt

# output to custom file name final.srt
python3 srt_merge.py subs1.srt subs2.srt -o final.srt
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import sys
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

# REQUIRED MODULE: pip3 install srt
import srt


def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x.start - pivot))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='merge SRT subtitles',
                                     usage="""
    Merge SRT subtitles:                                     
    \t{0} first.srt second.srt -o merged.srt
 """.format(Path(sys.argv[0]).name))

    parser.add_argument('srt1',
                        metavar='srt1',
                        help='SRT-file-1')
    parser.add_argument('srt2',
                        metavar='srt2',
                        help='SRT-file-2')
    parser.add_argument('--output-file', '-o',
                        default=None,
                        help='Output filename')
    parser.add_argument('--encoding', '-e',
                        default=None,
                        help='Input file encoding')
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

    srt1_path = Path(args.srt1)
    srt2_path = Path(args.srt2)

    with srt1_path.open(encoding=args.encoding or 'utf-8') as fi1:
        subs1 = {s.index: s for s in srt.parse(fi1)}

    with srt2_path.open(encoding=args.encoding or 'utf-8') as fi2:
        subs2 = {s.index: s for s in srt.parse(fi2)}

    # iterate all subs in srt2 and find the closest EXISTING slot in srt1
    sub: srt.Subtitle
    start: int
    for idx, sub in subs2.items():

        start: timedelta = sub.start
        sub_nearest_slot: srt.Subtitle = nearest(subs1.values(), start)
        sub_nearest_slot.content = f'{sub_nearest_slot.content}<br>{sub.content}'
        subs1[sub_nearest_slot.index] = sub_nearest_slot

    if not args.output_file:
        generated_srt = srt1_path.parent / (f'{srt1_path.stem}_MERGED_{srt1_path.suffix}')
    else:
        generated_srt = Path(args.output_file)

    with generated_srt.open(mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
        fout.write(srt.compose(list(subs1.values())))
```